# Mudar cor de divs de mesma classe de acordo com o texto que contém nelas (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

Tenho várias `divs` com a mesma classe, dentro delas tem o texto "FREE" ou "PAGO", nas que contém o texto "FREE" preciso que tenha uma cor e "PAGO" outra. Usei `:contains()` mas como são `divs` da mesma classe todas ficam com a mesma cor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode utilizar o própria tag :contains, conforme exemplo que fiz.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("div.divLista:contains('FREE')").css("background","red");
$("div.divLista:contains('PAGO')").css("background","green");

});
```

Segue o código no fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nnksesdm/2/

Espero ter ajudado.

Duvidas estou a disposição.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado mesmo! Funcionou perfeitamente :D Valeuuu

Comment: Show!!  nao esqueça de avaliar a questão positivamente. ;)